# Reset Informatica admin password

Tags: forgot-password, informatica

Am using informatica9.0. i lost the **admin password**.
can you pls suggest some ways to reset it.

i have the **encrypted password** with me which i took from repository tables..

is there a way to login using that **encrypted password**. i tried replacing admin encrypred password with *password* of other users, but not able to login

```
i have other user names that are active and i have passwordfor them
is there any ways that i can make them admin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to use the `pmpasswd` utility (found in the `\server\bin` folder) to generate a hash for a new password. You can then update the `OPB_USERS` record for the Administrator account with this hash to have it reset.

I would back up the value before you change it though, in case that doesn't work.